# Magento show only x number of attributes, after that show more options

Tags: php, magento

I have another question, on my site i have layered horizontal navigation. It works great but now i have modified it.

For some productcategories there are for eg. 12 attributes that will appear on categorielevel but i want to show only 5 attributes and after that you will have to click show more options.

I have build in an break line that regulate that only 5 attributes will showup, so only the show more options is left.

Answer (score 0):

I think that easiest way would be to put those additional links in a separate `<div />` or other element and set it to `display: none;` style. Then I would use a simple JavaScript code to show them on click on `Show more` link, e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="show-more-link">Show more</a>
<div style="display:none;" id="other-attributes">(the content)</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//use prototype for this matter
$('show-more-link').observe('click', function(){
  if ($('other-attributes')).visible() { //hide
    $('other-attributes').hide();
    this.update('Show more');
  } else {
    $('other-attributes').show();
    this.update('Show less');
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```

I haven't tested it, but I think something like this should work.